# Why http request call error callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

Why http request call error callback when data is returned from server? My code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MarkerList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:63342/testtask/data/markers.json').then(function() {
            console.log('success')
    }, function() {
            console.log('error')
    });
}]);
```

Console log:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:1033:14)
at defaults.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:6847:18)
at http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:6822:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:300:11)
at transformData (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:6821:3)
at transformResponse (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:7491:17)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:10689:81)
at http://localhost:63342/testtask/app/vendor/angular.js:10775:26 angular.js:9193
error
```

Comment: Seems like your API endpoint doesn't return valid json data

Comment: I have data.json with following content {a: 1}

Comment: are you sure, that the http server returns this as response? you could check this with your browsers dev tools

Comment: I solved problem. My JSON was wrongly issued.

Comment: You should consider posting how you solved the problem as an answer.